# About storing getchar() returned value inside a char-variable

Tags: c, getchar

I *know* the following code is broken --`getchar()` returns an `int` not a `char`--

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char single_byte = getchar();

  while (single_byte != EOF) {
    single_byte = getchar();
    printf("getchar() != EOF is %d.\n", single_byte != EOF);
    if (single_byte == EOF)
      printf("EOF is implemented in terms of 0x%x.\n", single_byte);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

though I would expect that a typical output of it (using `/dev/urandom` as the input-stream for instance) would have been at last `EOF is implemented in terms of 0xff`, and **not** the following

```
$ ./silly < /dev/urandom
getchar() != EOF is 1.
getchar() != EOF is 1.
// ...
getchar() != EOF is 0
EOF is implemented in terms of 0xffffffff.
```

Furthermore, `0xffffffff` cannot be stored into a single byte ...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I *know* the following code is broken --`getchar()` returns an `int` not a `char`--

Good!

```
char single_byte = getchar();
```

This is problematic is more than one way.

I'll assume `CHAR_BIT == 8` and `EOF == -1`. (We know `EOF` is negative and of type `int`; `-1` is a typical value -- and in fact I've never heard of it having any other value.)

Plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned.

If it's unsigned, the value of `single_byte` will be either the value of the character that was just read (represented as an `unsigned char` and trivially converted to plain `char`), or the result of converting `EOF` to `char`. Typically `EOF` is -1, and the result of the conversion will be `CHAR_MAX`, or 255. You won't be able to distinguish between `EOF` and an actual input value of 255 -- and since `/dev/urandom` returns all byte values with equal probability (and never runs dry), you'll see a `0xff` byte sooner or later.

But that won't terminate your input loop. Your comparison `(single_byte == EOF)` will never be true; since `single_byte` is of an unsigned type in this scenario, it can never be equal to `EOF`. You'll have an infinite loop, even when reading from a finite file rather than from an unlimited device like `/dev/urandom`. (You could have written `(single_byte == (char)EOF)`, but of course that would not solve the underlying problem.)

Since your loop does terminate, we can conclude that plain `char` is signed on your system.

If plain `char` is signed, things are a little more complicated. If you read a character in the range 0..127, its value will be stored in `single_byte`. If you read a character in the range 128..255, the `int` value is *converted* to `char`; since `char` is signed and the value is out of range, the result of the conversion is *implementation-defined*.  For most implementations, that conversion will map 128 to -128, 129 to -127, ... 255 to -1. If `getchar()` returns `EOF`, which is (typically) -1, the conversion is well defined and yields -1. So again, you can't distinguish between `EOF` and an input character with the value `-1`.

(Actually, as of C99, the conversion can also raise an implementation-defined signal. Fortunately, as far as I know, no implementations actually do that.)

```
if (single_byte == EOF)
    printf("EOF is implemented in terms of 0x%x.\n", single_byte);
```

Again, this condition will be true either if `getchar()` actually returned `EOF` or if you just read a character with the value `0xff`. The `%x` format requires an argument of type `unsigned int`. `single_byte` is of type `char`, which will almost certainly be promoted to `int`. Now you can print an `int` value with an `unsigned int` format *if* the value is within the representable range of both types. But since `single_byte`'s value is `-1` (it just compared equal to `EOF`), it's not in that range. `printf`, with the `"%x"` format, *assumes* that the argument is of type `unsigned int` (this isn't a conversion). And `0xffffffff` is the likely result of taking a 32-bit `int` value of `-1` and assuming that it's really an `unsigned int`.

And I'll just note that storing the result of `getchar()` in an `int` object would have been a whole lot easier than analyzing what happens when you store it in a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

End-of-File is a macro definition of type int that expands into a negative integral constant expression (generally, -1).

Comment: Sure, but after all I'm just printing the value of `single_byte` which is a `char`. I'm asking: how `single_byte` (which is **1** byte indeed) can be `0xffffffff`?

Comment: Did you try printing `EOF`? http://ideone.com/wHcIq8 - What you need to find out is what `EOF` evaluates to in your system. You will get your answer.

Comment: My perplexity is thus caused by the way I'm printing `single_byte`? Meaning that `%x` prints `-1` no matters where it comes from, yet using 2's complement on `1` thought as a 32bit word?, right? At first `single_byte` is evaluated then printed out the way instruction asks.

Comment: For unsigned integer types (size_t being one of those), the C standard specifies precise overflow rules. In short, if SIZE_MAX is the maximum value of the type size_t, then the expression

(size_t) (SIZE_MAX + 1)

is guaranteed to be 0, and therefore, you can be sure that (size_t) -1 is equal to SIZE_MAX.

Answer (score 0):

`EOF` is not a real character so in order to allow the result of `getchar()` return either a valid character or an `EOF`, it uses a hack whereas the return type is `int`. You have to cast it to `char` *after* you make sure it is not an `EOF`.

This is a textbook example of poorly designed API.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a confusion between `(char) -1` and `(int) -1`.

`getchar()` returns an `int` with 1 of 257 different values: 0 to 255 and EOF.  EOF is less than 0 (C11 7.21.1).

*Typically* EOF has the value of -1 and that is so in your case.  Let's assume that for the following.

From time to time, when data is read from `/dev/urandom`, a value of 255 is read.  This is *not* the EOF.

Given that OP performs `char single_byte = getchar()`, `single_byte` takes on the *same* value of `(char) -1` if `(int) -1` (EOF) was read or if `(int) 255` was read.

When next comparing `single_byte != EOF`, should the result be `false`, we do not know if original return value of `getchar()` was -1 or 255.

Recommend a different `printf()`

```
printf("single_byte==EOF, so (int) 255 or EOF was read: 0x%hhx\n", single_byte);
```

---

Assumptions:
`char` is 8 bits.
EOF is -1.

Comment: Sure, I knew that; that's why OP is broken: there are two bytes that overlap then the procedure stops after reading a random number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

```
EOF values are
EOF => %d => -1
EOF => %c => <prints blank space but not blank space>
EOF => %x => 0xFFFFFFFF
```

no ascii value for EOF! so basically you cannot compare the getchar() output with EOF. Reason is when you leave blank space and press enter ASCII value of a blank space is 0x20 (32 in decimal), If you press enter then ASCII of carriage return in 0x0D (13 in decimal).

So that piece of code will not work! either you have to define a value to exit the code!

Comment: uhm ...so you're saying that EX1-6 in K&R ('Verify that expression `getchar() != EOF` is `0` or `1`') is bad-stated?

Comment: I am sorry! your piece of code is an infinite loop! when I typed your piece of code never work meant It will never reach that if (single_byte == EOF).

Comment: I am sorry! your piece of code is an infinite loop! when I typed your piece of code never work meant It will never reach that if (single_byte == EOF), I should have made it clear my mistake. And EX1-6 in K&R is not bad stated! It is an infinite loop until you actually break the execution of the program. in that example value of c is always 1 (which is always != 0).